# Cleaning up after gruntjs encounters a fail code

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, gruntjs

I have a grunt task like so:

```
grunt.registerTask 'test', ['clean:test',
                          'coffee:test',
                          'mochaTest',
                          'clean:test']
```

If mochaTest returns with a fail code, the last clean won't run and will leave unwanted transpiled files.
It doesn't throw an error so I can't try/catch/finally and google/reading source code doesn't provide me with a solution except for manually running `grunt clean:test` after each fail.

Am I going about this the wrong way, or is there a nifty way to do something similar to a finally-block?

(I know I can run mocha using coffee-files, this is a simplified example problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did to solve this was in my Makefile to add

test: grunt test && grunt clean:test

to ensure a proper cleanup even after a failed test.

$make test
to run it.

Answer (score 1):

The reason the final `'clean:test'` doesn't run is that Grunt is designed to stop on failures. If you used the `--force` option (`grunt test --force`) you could cause it to continue after the failure of `mochaTest`. This is not a good habit to get into, or would not make sense in cases where your chain of tasks was longer, more interdependent, or more complex.